# Sequentially changing directory and running a script

Tags: command-line, bash

For the life of me, I cannot find any help on this at all. I have, say, 2000 directories that I need to run a specific program in. Due to program limitations, it cannot simply write 'Output1', 'Output2', 'Output3', etc. It has to write 'Output' as it's output file and will overwrite any other file named 'Output', hence the need for a directory for each unique instance of the program. What i need is something to this effect

With s being the prefix for the directory. I. E., s0001, s0002....s2000 being the directory names.

```
cd s(n)
ls
cd s(n+1)
```

and having this looping command stop after

```
cd s2000
```

. I was trying to make it work by an

```
if 'cd s(n+1)' = 'cd s(2001)' then echo DONE
```

string, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your last line code is not a bash syntax it won't work.

Comment: @jcklasseter how are your directories organized, by the way ?

Comment: If I understand correctly (not sure if I do) you are creating separate directories because of name issues? If so, it would be more efficient to make a script rename the file before running the next instance. Both running your application and the renaming can be combined then. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: They're organized numerically @Serg, if that's what you mean. If I go to the top directory, there's folders s0001 - s2000 in order. And Jacob, I have to have separate directories because the Program I will be using for the 2000 tasks writes an identically named output for each Job and I need every unique output file for each set in input parameters. The submission of each job is Identical from file to file, But I have to separate the files somehow.

Comment: @bolzano you're right, my bad. I hadn't actually tried it because I knew it wouldn't work, but it was food for thought in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details depend on your setup. If the parent directory only contains the child directories s0001 to s2000, all you need is to iterate over them and launch the program in each:

```
for d in s*; do
  cd "$dir" && run_program; cd ../;
done
```

That will move into each dir and lauch `run_program`. Once that is finished, it moves back.

If you need to specify a range of dirs, use this instead:

```
for dir in s{0001..2000}; do
    cd "$dir" && run_program; cd ../
done
```

Finally, if you want to launch all processes simultaneously (not that this might bring your computer to its knees), use `&`:

```
for dir in s{0001..2000}; do
    cd "$dir" && run_program & cd ../
done
```

---

Older versions of bash don't expand `{001..002}` as `001 002` but as `1 2` instead. If your bash doesn't support this, use this approach instead:

```
seq 1 2000 | while read i; do 
   dir=$(printf '%0.4d\n' "$i")
   cd s"$dir" && run_program; cd ../;
done
```

The trick is to generate the numbers between 1 and 2000 using `seq` and then use `printf` to add leading 0s as needed.

Comment: If I have flags in my command or whitespace, will that be an issue or will I need to quote it?

Comment: @jcklasseter no, no need for quoting. This is a normal shell command. For example, `for d in s*; do ls -ltr ; done` will work as expected.

Comment: Okay. Another thing, will I be able to string together multiple commands separated by & signs, or is there another way?

Comment: I think I have it. I want it to '&& run_program; store output into log.txt & cd ../' . I'm sorry, but I'm also a little confused on the best way to store the programs confirmation number into a log file in the middle.

Comment: @jcklasseter what confirmation number? Come into the site [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping me (`@terdon`) there. It will be easier to explain that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash script. Feel free to adapt it to suit your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
BASEDIR=/home/xieerqi

find "$BASEDIR" -type d -name "s[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' folder; do
        echo "$folder"
        cd "$folder"
        echo "TEST" | tee filez{1,2,3}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this python script

```
import os
def main():
    a = 100
    while a>1:
        os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/s000"+a))
        do your work here
        a = a-1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where the while loop changes to the directory until it is equal to 1. and you can change the value of a according to your wish and at "do your work here", write what you want to do.

Comment: Will this work if I use a non standard command (Not using ls or cp)? Lets say I use the command foo, which is not an alias to anything. It is however, recognized by the base system as a valid command. On the same toke, will I need to quote the command or anything? I've no clue regarding python, if you can't tell. Thanks!

Comment: When I say non standard, I mean it's not a general python term. I did look that Up.

Comment: "Standard" unix commands like `ls` are on exactly the same footing with other executable programs: You cannot simply call them from python. "do your work here" will have to involve launching your program as a subprocess. Why you'd want to bring python into this I have no idea.

Comment: you can simply call the unix commands in python through subprocess it's not a big deal :)

Answer (score 0):

The program always writes `Output`, but you don't have to leave it that way. If the program's settings are controlled from the command line, you can simply run the program and rename the output as soon as it finishes:

```
for dirname in `ls -d s*`
do
    myprogram "$dirname"
    mv Output Output-"$dirname"
done
```

Of course I don't know what parameter arguments your program accepts, because you don't say. If it actually reads from lots of files, it make still make sense to have separate directories. But "the output name is fixed" is in itself no reason to go to all this trouble.

PS. Don't use parentheses in your filenames. They have special meaning to the shell and confuse your scripts unless you know how to deal with them.

Comment: It actually reads a lot of individual files and outputs many more. Thanks though!

Comment: So the _inputs_ are already in separate directories? *That's* the important information. How does it decide what to use?